# Where is my VMware-ws FreeNAS CIFS(ZFS) bottle-neck?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, freenas, zfs, cifs

**Background:** I'm building a quiet HTPC + NAS that is also supposed to be used for general computer usage. I'm so far generally happy with things, it was just that I was expecting a little better IO performance. I have no clue if my expectations are unreal. The NAS is there as a general purpose file storage and as a media server for XBMC and other devices. ZFS is a requirement.

**Question:** Where is my bottle-neck, and is there anything I can do config wise, to improve my performance? I'm thinking VM-disk settings could be something but I really have no idea where to go since I'm neither experienced with FreeNAS nor VMware-WS.

**Tests:**
When I'm on the host OS and copy files (from the SSD) to the CIFS share, I get around 30 Mbytes/sec read and write. When I'm on my laptop laptop, wired to the network, I get about the same specs. The test I've done are with a 16 GB ISO, and with about 200 MB of RARs and I've tried avoiding the RAM-cache by reading different files than the ones I'm writing (> 10 GB). It feels like having less CPU cores is a lot more efficient, since the resource manager in Windows reports less CPU-usage. With 4 cores in VMware, CPU usage was 50-80%, with 1 core it was 25-60%.

**EDIT:**

HD ActiveTime was quite high on SSD so I moved the page file, disabled hibernate and enabled Win DiskCache both on SSD and RAID. This resulted in no real performance difference for one file, but if i transferred 2 files the total speed went up to 50 Mbytes/s vs ~40. The ActiveTime avg also went down a lot (to ~20%) but has now higher bursts. DiskIO is on ~ 30-35 Mbytes/s avgs, with ~100Mb bursts. Network is on 200-250Mbits/s with ~45 active TCP connections.

**Hardware**

- Asus F2A85-M Pro
- A10-5700
- 16GB DDR3 1600
- OCZ Vertex 2 128GB SSD
- 2x Generic 1tb 7200 RPM drives as RAID0 (in win7)
- Intel Gigabit Desktop CT

**Software**

- Host OS: Win7 (SSD)
- VMware Worksation 9 (SSD)
- FreeNAS 8.3 VM (20GB VDisk on SSD)

  - CPU: I've tried 1, 2 and 4 cores.
  - Virtualisation engine, Preferred mode: Automatic
  - 10,24Gb ram
  - 50Gb SCSI VDisk on the RAID0, VDisk is formatted as ZFS and exposed through CIFS through FreeNAS.
  - NIC Bridge, Replicate physical network state

**Below are two typical process print-outs while I'm transfering one file to the CIFS share.**

```
last pid:  2707;  load averages:  0.60,  0.43,  0.24  up 0+00:07:05    00:34:26
32 processes:  2 running, 30 sleeping
Mem: 101M Active, 53M Inact, 1620M Wired, 2188K Cache, 149M Buf, 8117M Free
Swap: 4096M Total, 4096M Free

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND
 2640 root          1 102    0 50164K 10364K RUN      0:25 25.98% smbd
 1897 root          6  44    0   168M 74808K uwait    0:02  0.00% python
```

---

```
last pid:  2746;  load averages:  0.93,  0.60,  0.33  up 0+00:08:53    00:36:14
33 processes:  2 running, 31 sleeping
Mem: 101M Active, 53M Inact, 4722M Wired, 2188K Cache, 152M Buf, 5015M Free
Swap: 4096M Total, 4096M Free

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND
 2640 root          1  76    0 50164K 10364K RUN      0:52 16.99% smbd
 1897 root          6  44    0   168M 74816K uwait    0:02  0.00% python
```

---

I'm sorry if my question isn't phrased right, I'm really bad at these kind of things, and it is the first time I post here at SU. I also appreciate any other suggestions to something, I could have missed.

Comment: Is that *software/BIOS* RAID-0? How much I/O is occurring on the host OS hard disks, the RAID0 volume? RAID in software (or BIOS) is terrible; you shouldn't use RAID without a hardware RAID controller, pretty much end of story. It can cause mostly invisible CPU usage and I/O storms on the host that bog down the entire system.

Comment: Copying data from the SSD to the RAID drive (NoVM) goes at around 150+ Mbytes/s with CPU usage going up about 5%, I have a hardware raid I think (how do I check?). I've set the SATA ports to RAID in the BIOS and I've set the RAID defs when it loads the controllers pre win. As far as the VM is concerned I think it sees the RAID as a really fast disk. Copying data from host to CIFS results in a ~35Mbyte/s SSD read and a ~30Mbyte RAID write. Not sure if it helped.

Comment: If you don't know for a fact that you have specifically purchased a Hardware RAID card (for example an Adaptec 6405E), you aren't using hardware RAID. BIOS RAID is just as bad as software RAID. The CPU is used for coordinating the striping.

Comment: Is this related specifically for VM-ware IO? Since I get more than 150Mbytes/s in windows SSD-->RAID0 with almost no CPU usage and I'm happy with the performance there, but maybe VMWare can't handle the type of raid that I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck could be several things:

- VM and Data is stored in the same ssd
- in bridged mode -> router could be the bottle neck too

Check These links:

http://www.seancull.co.uk/public/seancull.nsf/dx/is-your-vmware-workstation-network-really-slow-solved-.htm

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2019058

Comment: I'll check this out and update how it goes. Thank you.